Cartan decomposition of $\mathfrak{so}(3,2)$
Consider the Lie group $SO(2,3) =\{X\in GL(5, \mathbb R) \mid A^t B A = B\}$ and its Lie algebra $$\mathfrak{so}(2,3) = \{A\in GL(5, \mathbb R) \mid A^t B + BA=0\}$$ where $B = \text{diag}(1,1, 1, -1,-1)$.
Let $K$ be the maximal compact subgroup of $SO(3,2)$, we can take $K= O(2) \times O(3)$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{k} = \mathfrak{o}(2)\oplus \mathfrak{o}(3)$, which is
\begin{align}
\mathfrak{o}(2)\oplus \mathfrak{o}(3)
&= \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & w_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -w_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & x_1 & x_2 \\ 0 & 0 & -x_1 & 0 & y_1 \\ 0 & 0 & -x_2 & -y_1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \right\}
\end{align}
I want to find out the explicit Cartan decomposition of $\mathfrak{so}(2,3) = \mathfrak{k} \oplus \mathfrak{k}^{\perp}$.

I have some doubts. Is my description of $\mathfrak{k} = \mathfrak{o}(2)\oplus \mathfrak{o}(3)$ right? Is this decomposition $\mathfrak{g} = \mathfrak{k}\oplus \mathfrak{k}^{\perp}$ w.r.t the killing bilinear form on $\mathfrak{so}(2,3)$ i.e.  $B(X, Y) = 3\text{tr}(XY)$? Can anyone please help me to find out the explicit Cartan decomposition?

I think you mean $\mathfrak{gl}(5,\mathbb{R})$ in the definition of the Lie algebra.
You are correct that the maximal compact is $\mathfrak{so}(3) \oplus \mathfrak{so}(2)$ (or $\mathfrak{o}(3) \oplus \mathfrak{o}(2)$ but you should aim to be consistent with using $\mathfrak{so}$ or $\mathfrak{o}$). You do have the blocks the wrong way round compared to your definition of the bilinear form. To match your definition of it you would have:
$$ \mathfrak{k} = \left\{\left.\begin{pmatrix}A&0\\0&B\end{pmatrix}\right| A \in \mathfrak{o}(3), B \in \mathfrak{o}(2)\right\} $$
(i.e. the first block is of size $3$)
Then the noncompact part is simply:
$$ \mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{k}^\perp = \left\{\left.\begin{pmatrix}0&C\\C^T&0\end{pmatrix}\right| C \in M_{3,2}\right\} $$
You can quickly verify these if you do the calculations as block matrices as I have written them and that they are orthogonal w.r.t. to the Killing form/trace form should be clear as well.

Thanks you for answer. I have mixed up the notations. If $\mathfrak{g}= \mathfrak{so}(2,3)$, then is $ \mathfrak{k}^\perp = \left{\left.\begin{pmatrix}0&C\C^T&0\end{pmatrix}\right| C \in M_{2,3}\right}$

@NeelanjanMondal $\mathfrak{so}(2,3)$ and $\mathfrak{so}(3,2)$ are the same Lie algebra (up to isomorphism) so it was only really your definition of the bilinear form $B$ that mismatched. If you swap that for $\text{diag}(1,1,-1,-1,-1)$ (or $\text{diag}(-1,-1,1,1,1)$) then yes you will get that as $\mathfrak{k}^\perp$
